# Failed connect session manager: Failed connect to session manager: IO error occured opening connection

Tags: xfce4, xfce4-terminal

I was following this tutorial [about setting up i3 on wsl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV2GOHFvTvQ)

startxfce4 results in error: "xfce5-panel: Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: IO error occured opening connection"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs with permission issues, try: sudo -u youruser startxfce4

Comment: This line helps me to be able to startxfce. However, the whole session will be run as root which should not be like that. So, we still need to have solution without sudo

Comment: Using sudo -u phill startxfce4, will start xfce4 session as user phill and not root, but xfce4 will be running with sudo privilege. if session open is root, then is because you have forgot to specify the username after "-u".